VHF / UHF modules for custom radio build
I’ve been looking at VHF / UHF modules for a potential custom HT build:

DRA818V
SA818-U

I came across a project that uses a module like this with an ESP32 to make a radio that is controlled via an Android phone.
I’m surprised how little circuitry is needed for the radio module in this project. I’m curious if anyone has experience with modules like this?
I’m basically wondering how well these work. My interests are more around the software to drive a DIY HT, and not optimizations for the radio hardware. I’ve done several projects with ESP32 modules and am curious about just the radio module, not the ESP32, UART, power etc. Is it a pipe dream to think I could use one of these modules as-is without a bunch of extra radio related circuitry (ex: filtering)? My goal would be the build a decently functioning radio. Think like Baofeng or better. Not Yaesu/Icom level quality.
I’d appreciate your thoughts!

Both of those modules are built around the RDA1846 which means that what you get is, in most senses, identical to a Baofeng, only with a lower output power.

Those modules appear to have RF interface at 50 ohm and both TX and RX come to the same pin (internally switched). So, you'll just need an LPF to suppress harmonics and an antenna.
If you make the rest of it work, it would not be hard to have someone collaborate or advise you on the LPF part.
The spec for that LPF is very simple, but it would be good to measure the harmonic levels from the bare board first, then design and test an LPF, and then confirm the final emission as a system. The VHF version is easier to build and work with, so I would start there.
https://d3s5r33r268y59.cloudfront.net/datasheets/2570/2014-06-03-08-38-29/SA818%20Datasheet.pdf
https://www.dorji.com/docs/data/DRA818V.pdf?ref=news.itsfoss.com
However, all that is assuming we can trust what's in those spec sheets (not much details  are in there to convince me).

Thanks. What do you mean by the collaboration part being hard? Are you referring to not being able to ask the manufacturer what a suitable LPF design would be? Versus having to build one and test it out to see if it attenuates frequencies above the max frequency of the module, then adjust? Basically trial and error.

Sorry that was my careless writing. I realized that and edited a few minutes before you posted your comment. The spec for that LPF is very simple, but it would be good to measure the harmonic levels from the bare board first, then design and test an LPF, and then confirm the final emission as a system.
